# Issues with if, else and elif

Tags: python, if-statement, while-loop

I am new to python and have currently hit a roadblock in my code. I know this may be way too obvious to notice but I couldn't get it around my head. I am currently trying to write a code as to asking a bunch of questions and letting the user know what to do during a pandemic, and only accepts the user to enter y or n and if the user enters anything else, the code will ask the user to enter again

```
yesChoice=["y", "Y"]
noChoice=["n", "N"]
while True:
    HRW=input("Did you receive a Health Risk Warning(HRW) Notice (y/n)?: ")
    if HRW==yesChoice:
        print("Follow protocol of 3-5 days of monitoring, test ART within 24 hrs")
    elif HRW==noChoice:
        well=input("Are you feeling well (y/n)?: ")
        if well==noChoice:
            print("Visit a doctor to assess on the next step")
        else:
            print("For safety measures, please do an ART test")
    else:
        print("Please enter y/n")
        continue
```

There are more that I will be adding into the code for further steps but currently when I typed in y, it will just keep printing "Please enter y/n" and keep asking "Did you receive a Health Risk Warning(HRW) Notice (y/n)". What exactly is the issue here? Thanks in advance!

Comment: Change `if HRW==yesChoice` to `if HRW in yesChoice`. Similarly for other tests.

Comment: Change the code to use `in`: `if HRW in yesChoice:`

Comment: Make sure you change the issue mentioned by jarmod and Timur Shtatland in all 3 appropriate places where you currently have `==`. Each of them need to use `in` because yesChoice and noChoice are both lists.

Answer (score 5):

The operation `==` returns if a value is equal to another value, such as if the input string is strictly equal to `yes`. Because you want to test if it’s in the list, you should use `in`:

```py
if HRW in yesChoice:
    doSomething()
```